# Does any function from the exec family in unix not ignore SIGINT?

Tags: exec, signals

Is it possible to start a process with `exec` and have that process run in the background, and (unlike `System()`), will that process be `kill`ed once an interrupt signal is passed to the parent process that created it?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.  Ignoring SIGINT is a behavior specific to system().  If you roll your own system() using fork() and execl(), you won't get that.

Of course, unless you're really careful you're going to make zombies.

Comment: Not sure about the zombie comment - if the parent ignores the SIGCHLD signal, no zombies will be created.   Also, the process can wait for its child (or children) to die, just like system() does - or it can run asynchronously with the child running at the same time.

Comment: Those options are pretty much what I mean by "being really careful". :)